# rTorrent XMLRPC command help - schedule pause/restart of all torrents

Tags: scripting, rtorrent

I would like to create a XMLRPC command and add to rtorrent.rc to schedule pausing and resuming all torrents.

Reading the docs I figured out the following but something is missing and the command doesn't work.

Command to pause all torrents at a given time every 24 hours:

`schedule2 = pause_torrents, 01:10:00, 24:00:00, ((d.multicall2=,d.pause=))`

For resuming would just use `d.resume` command.
For stopping or starting would use `d.stop` or `d.start` respectively.

Can you provide the solution?

Comment: Welcome, It is not a scripting question. It is about  XMLRPC commands.

Comment: Thx. Replaced scripting with command. Question remains.